# Include Chapter number in reference if target is in different chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm using a setup where the chapter numbers are in `Roman` and the *normal* referencing commands do not include a chapter reference:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

As long as I'm referencing content in the same chapter everything is fine, however, sometimes (not very often) I reference content from a different chapter. In these rare cases I manually add `in \Cref{chap:Chapter-Ref}` to the reference. Obviously this is both cumbersome and prone to error!

As you can already see, I'm using `cleveref`, however, it appears it is not clever enough to automagically detect that it should insert a chapter reference when I'm referencing cross-chapter. I would assume that it has all the required information buried somewhere deep in its internals. After reading its documentation I am no wiser nonetheless: If there is some solution apparent in there, I missed it.

> How can I [read: you ;-) ] change the reference command such that it inserts a chapter reference whenever the target of a reference command is in a different chapter?

I have tried to obtain a *first solution* using the mechanisms provided by the `zref` package, however, I failed miserably.

Below you'll find a tiny MWE for convenience :-)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chap}
\label{chap:foo}
\Cref{chap:foo} should print \textit{Chapter I}. \Cref{chap:foo} should print \textit{Chapter II}. \Cref{sec:foo} should print \textit{Section 1}.
\section{A Section}
\label{sec:foo}

\chapter{Scnd Chap}
\label{chap:bar}

\Cref{chap:foo} should print \textit{Chapter I}. \Cref{chap:foo} should print \textit{Chapter II}. \Cref{sec:foo} should print \textit{Section 1 in Chapter I}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed a duplicate although this one is much older than the duplicate ;-)